# linux hw_breakpoint does not work while accessing memory from userspace

Tags: debugging, memory, linux-kernel, breakpoints

I am debugging a ARMv7 board and I want to know whether a kernel symbol is accessed. So I have to use hw_breakpoint in kernel.

For simplicity, I use kernel sample code:data_breakpoint to test, which locates in [`samples/hw_breakpoint/data_breakpoint.c`](http://140.136.149.249/lxr/source/the-tree/samples/hw_breakpoint/data_breakpoint.c).

Then I did the following operation:

```
insmod data_breakpoint.ko ksym=max
cat /proc/kallsyms | grep max
./read_kmem c06fa128
```

But this did not trigger the callback function.

If I print the value in that address in any kernel module, callback function will be triggered.

I read the cpu manual and it says that the breakpoint register in my cpu support virtual address matching. But I don't know why it doesn't work while accessing memory from userspace. I think that program does read the right value of kernel symbol.

read_kmem.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define DEVKMEM         "/dev/kmem"

#define PAGE_SIZE       0x1000
#define PAGE_MASK       (~(PAGE_SIZE-1))


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int fd;
    char *mbase;
    char read_buf[10];
    unsigned int varAddr;

    varAddr = strtoul(argv[1], 0, 16);

    unsigned int ptr = varAddr & ~(PAGE_MASK);

    fd = open(DEVKMEM, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(-1);
    }

    mbase = mmap(0,PAGE_SIZE,PROT_READ,MAP_SHARED,fd, (varAddr & PAGE_MASK));
    if (mbase == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("map failed %s\n",strerror(errno));
    }

    printf("varAddr = 0x%X \n", varAddr);
    printf("mapbase = 0x%X \n", (unsigned int)mbase);
    printf("value   = 0x%X \n",*(unsigned int*)(mbase+ptr));

    close(fd);
    munmap(mbase,PAGE_SIZE);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your userspace does not access address c06fa128, it accesses a different address - one that that mmap() returned (plus offset). Thus no breakpoint hit.

The fact that virtual address being accessed resolves to same physical address as some other virtual address that has a breapoint, does not matter. CPU executing your userspace code has no idea that different mapping exists.